# How to create a html button that runs a php script?

Tags: php, html, button

i want to create a button in html that runs a php script, 
i have this script:

```
<?php 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
if (!$user->guest) : ?>
    <a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo $userToken; ?>=1" class="btn">Log out</a>
```

and i want to use it in a html button

any help?

Comment: Can you provide more details, your description doesn't really help...

Comment: You should look up AJAX.

Comment: As u can see, i posted a script in php that i want to run, and i want to run it when i click on a button (that button is coded in html), is that possible? (i'm new to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call a js function onclick of your button and send ajax request on your script file to run php script...

```
<input type="button"  value="Run Script"  onclick="run_script();"/>

<script>
function run_()
{
    $.post("yourScripFile.php",function(data){
        if(data != null)
        {
            alert(data);
        }   
     });
}
</script>
```

And in your php script file

```
<?php 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
if (!$user->guest)
{
     echo  '<a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&'.$userToken.'=1" class="btn">Log out</a>';
     die;   
} 
else
{
    echo "else code here"; die;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$_POST` or `$_GET` parameter and pass it with the click of the button. Just put the script in an if block in the same page `if($_GET['act'] == "logout"){//run script}` and add `?act=logout` to your url when you want to trigger the script. Instead of `$_GET` you can use `$_POST` and a hidden input named `act`